# Select2 ver.2.6.4 plugin for oracle Apex ver.5.0.3

Tags: oracle, jquery-select2-4, oracle-apex-5, jquery-select2

When I import the plugin into my workspace on oracle apex ver 5.0.3 no error occurs. Then I try to use the item plugin in a modal window in my project. If it is checked for lazy loading, nothing appears on window. If it is not checked for lazy loading, then it appears on window with no functionality of the plugin. It is like I have used select list from standard apex items.

I have tried the same in oracle apex ver 5.0.0 and it works fine.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Which plugin do you use?

Comment: The maintainer of the plugin (Nick) is quite responsive, have you tried contacting him? https://github.com/nbuytaert1/apex-select2/issues